# Puzzle about inheritance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I know the concept of inheritance in JavaScript is through prototype chain, but I'm not sure I understand it right. When a property is been read, the engine will first search for the instance's own property, if not found will search for the [[Prototype]] property of the instance, which is a reference to the prototype of the function that creates the instance, the search will go on until it reaches to the Object.prototype. For the following code:

```
var person1 = {
    name: "Qiushi",
    sayName: function() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
};

person1.sayName();  // Qiushi

var person2 = Object.create(person1);
person2.name = "Alex";
console.log(person2.hasOwnProperty("sayName")); // false
person2.sayName();  // Alex
```

when person2 is inherit from person1, so that person2 can use the method defined in person1. But the *sayName* method is not a property of the prototype of person1, but instead it is just a own property of it. My question is as the method searching is following alone the prototype chain, how would *person2* use a method which is not in this chain?

-------------------------------FINAL EDIT-------------------------

If you have same concern for the problem, please read the conversation between me and Jimbo.

Comment: It *is* in the chain, only not *owned* (not defined on `person2` prototype). That's why we have `hasOwnProperty()` in the first place.

Comment: Here's something to think about: There is no inheritance in JavaScript. Nothing inherits anything from anywhere, ever. All there is is a *singly linked list* of objects called the *prototype chain*. The objects in that list are searched, in order, for properties with a given name. Either an object has a certain property defined (then `hasOwnProperty()` is true for that particular object), or one of its parents in the chain has (then `hasOwnProperty()` is true for that particular parent, but false for the initial object), or none has, then the property is undefined.

Comment: @Tomalak: "There is no inheritance in JavaScript" is simply untrue. Just because the inheritance mechanism is readily explained, that doesn't make it not inheritance. The inheritance mechanisms of Java and C++ are readily explained as well.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know, and we agree on that point. The purpose of the comment was to break the common thought pattern that an inherited property somehow becomes an *actual part* of the object at the end of the prototype chain. If I replace one element of an object's prototype chain, that object immediately appears to have different properties. Prototypical inheritance mimics the effects of inheritance, but the objects in question do not *really* get the properties they respond to (as opposed to how it works in Java/C++).

Comment: @Tomalak: It's not mimicking, it's just a different mechanism. Agreed on the way it's different, and how that can surprise people. (Amusingly, you also regularly see Java questions where the OP has thought in terms of separate objects, one for the base class part and another for the derived part, and gotten confused *that* way. :-) )

Comment: Maybe they should have called it property sharing instead of inheritance. ;) Anyway, it is was what confused *me* in the beginning and I thought sharing the train of thought that made me get it would be worthwhile.

Comment: @Tomalak, `document.body instanceof HTMLElement === true`

Comment: @haim770 I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.create` returns a new object where the supplied argument **is** the prototype object of the new object.

So you've now got this:

```
{person2}
    - name:'Alex'
    - {prototype}
        - name:'Quishi'
        - sayName:function
```

So if you look for the property `name` on person2, it will find that property on person2 itself, and not look on the prototype. If you look for `sayName` it will not find it on person2, so it will look on the prototype and find it there.

The `this` keyword will reference in the function depends on where the function is called FROM. That's just how `this` works. When you call a method on an object the object will be the `this` inside that method. So even though the method is on the prototype, `this` will still reference person2 if you call `person2.sayName();`. If you were to change that (such as via `.call`) you could change the output.

```
console.log(person2.name); // -> Alex

person2.sayName(); // -> Alex
person2.sayName.call(person2.__proto__); // -> Quishi, even though called on person2

person1.sayName(); // -> Quishi
person1.sayName.call(person2); // -> Alex, even though called on person1
```

I point this out because there's just as much possibility for misunderstanding `this` in this example as there is for misunderstanding prototypes.

Comment: guess I messed up the prototype and the prototype property of the object. To be more specific, when a property is not found in the own properties, the search engine will goes to the prototype of it, which is the object the current instance based on, rather than going to the prototype property of the current instance.

Comment: @photosynthesis - what you just said didn't make much sense. First off, understand that `Object.create` is just a way of making a new object while specifying its prototype (something that wasn't originally publicly accessible on objects). It doesn't play a role in what the fundamental nature of what _prototypes are_ or how they're to be handled. In this case we just specified that we wanted our `person2` object's prototype to be  the object `person1`. Therefore when the engine doesn't find a property on `person2` and checks `person2.__proto__` what it finds IS a reference to `person1`.

Comment: so every object created from object literal has its [[Prototype]] property pointed to the Object.prototype. So what does the [[Prototype]] property of person2 points to, person1 or person1.prototype?

Comment: @photosynthesis - In fact, `Object.create` wasn't even originally part of JS. In fact, all it is is a **user made** function by Douglas Crockford where he figured out a nice way to make new objects and manually determine their prototype...and the spec makers liked it so much they added it to the actual spec. You are treating it like it's a fundamental part of prototype inheritance itself...it is not. It's just a function for working with prototypes and objects.

Comment: @photosynthesis - there's no pointing of [[Prototype]] to Object.prototype...they're just 2 terms for the same thing. The prototype of an object was not traditionally accessible. So it is referred to as the inaccessible property [[Prototype]] to distinguish that we weren't actually talking about a property you could just access with a dot operator. But with functions you can just go `.prototype` to access it, so some people talk like that with objects even though it doesn't actually work. Both have prototypes...it just wasn't publicly accessible on objects. The new `__proto__` changes this.

Comment: I think when we are using new to create an object, that object's [[Prototype]] property is pointed to the constructor's [[Prototype]] property. While when we use B = Object.create(A) to implement inheritance, B's [[Prototype]] property is pointed to A directly. Do you think it make sense?

Comment: I read the book again and noticed the following sentence: "An instance keeps track of its prototype through an internal property called [[Prototype]]. This property is a pointer back to the prototype object that the instance is using. When you create a new object using new, the constructor’s prototype property is assigned to the [[Prototype]] property of that new object”

Comment: @photosynthesis - Yes, that's pretty much what happens. Using `new` will make an instance and that instance's [[Prototype]] will be the constructor function's [[Prototype]]. That's why things like an instance of an Array can have the method `slice` called on it, because the Array function's prototype has a slice function, and so the instance's [[Prototype]] has that function. And `Object.create` is just a different way of doing things where you explicitly determine what the [[Prototype]] ends up by actually _making_ an object then assigning that object as the [[Prototype]].

Comment: phew, we finally reach a conclusion, thank you very much.

Comment: @photosynthesis - Basically Crockford didn't like the whole `new` operator because it's an attempt to mimic the syntax of class based inheritance, and JS uses prototype based inheritance internally. He thought that fact only obscured how JS works by hiding what was happening with the [[Prototype]]. He figured that a method of making new instances where you're explicitly assigning the prototypes to those instances would, in the end, result in more people actually understanding what's happening and why, leading to better overall JS programming in the world. And so he made `Object.create`.

Comment: Gotcha, that make sense.

Answer (score 6):

There's nothing special about the objects that are prototypes of other objects, they're just objects.

When the engine goes to read a property, first it looks at the object itself to see if it has it and, if it does, uses it. If it doesn't, it looks to the prototype of the object, and then to *its* prototype, etc.

In your code, `person1` is the prototype of `person2`, so when looking up `sayName` on `person2`, since the engine doesn't find it on `person2`, it looks on `person2`'s prototype, `person1`, and finds it.

Here's a simple ASCII-art diagram of what you've set up in your code:

```
                                  +-------------------+
person1-----------------------+-->|     (object)      |
                              |   +-------------------+
                              |   | __proto__         |-->(not shown, Object.prototype)
                              |   | name: "Qiushi"    |
                              |   | sayName: function |
                              |   +-------------------+
                              |
            +--------------+  |
person2---->|   (object)   |  |
            +--------------+  |
            | __proto__    |--+
            | name: "Alex" |
            +--------------+
```

Here's a more-but-still-not-entirely complete version:

```
          +------------+                                  
Object--->| (function) |  +->(not shown, Function.prototype)                              
          +------------+  |                                 
          | __proto__  |--+                                  +--------------------+
          | prototype  |---------------------------------+-->|      (object)      |
          +------------+                                 |   +--------------------+
                                  +-------------------+  |   |   __proto__: null  |
person1-----------------------+-->|     (object)      |  |   | toString: function |
                              |   +-------------------+  |   | valueOf: function  |
                              |   | __proto__         |--+   | ...                |
                              |   | name: "Qiushi"    |      +--------------------+
                              |   | sayName: function |   
                              |   +-------------------+   
                              |                           
            +--------------+  |
person2---->|   (object)   |  |
            +--------------+  |
            | __proto__    |--+
            | name: "Alex" |
            +--------------+
```

Comment: Nice going with the diagrams.

Comment: so the prototype indicated here is just another object based on which the current object got created, rather than the [[prototype]] property of the current object, is that right?

Comment: @photosynthesis: The `[[prototype]]` property (shown above as `__proto__`) is a property that refers to the object's prototype, which **is** "just another object based on which the current object got created". :-) Prototype objects aren't special, they're just normal objects that happen to have another object's `[[prototype]]` property referring to them.